# FireStore Security rules : How to restrict update/write to a certain field un a document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Use case :
Every user document has quite a few fields but you want one field like birthdate to never be updated after a user signs up (so it's only written once when user signs up then never updated again)
How to write the rule for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can access document fields using request.resource.data.{field}

for our example, it will be

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
    // the name is not changed
    match /users/{user} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.dob == resource.data.dob;
    }
  }
}
```

This means that the document can be updated as long as dob hasn't changed which is what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: Were you able to get it working with the above code you posted?

Comment: @MaryM : yup it worked perfectly for me , Do you still have a problem ?